# UIView in custom UITableViewCell is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to build something like a facebook feed with a UITableView. However, I have a custom UITableViewCell with some Strings and I want to add another UIView, where I can add a Videoplayer. But somehow, I cannot see the additional UIView.

This is what I see at the moment:

[image]

Here is my code of my custom TableViewCell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LandingPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
var post : Post?

lazy var nameLabel = createUITextView()
lazy var uriLabel = createUITextView()
lazy var dateLabel = createUITextView()

var testView : UIView = {
    //let testView = UIView.init()
    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    testView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    testView.backgroundColor = .blue
    testView.clipsToBounds = true
    return testView
}()

var otherTestView : UIView = {
    //let otherTestView = UIView.init()
    let otherTestView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
    otherTestView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    otherTestView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    otherTestView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    otherTestView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 130.0/255.0, blue: 230.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    otherTestView.clipsToBounds = true
    return otherTestView
}()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.setupViews()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let post = post {
        nameLabel.text = "\(post.author.firstName!) \(post.author.lastName!)"
        uriLabel.text = post.video.uri
        dateLabel.text = post.createdAt
    }

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() -> () {
    self.contentView.addSubview(testView)
    self.contentView.addSubview(otherTestView)

    testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherTestView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    otherTestView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    otherTestView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    otherTestView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    otherTestView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func createUITextView() -> UILabel {
    let textView = UILabel()
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return textView
}
}
```

**I do not understand, why I do not see "otherTestView" with a black background and my "uriLabel" inside?**

My tableview rowheight is set to automaticDimension:

```
self.postsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Please tell me if you need any other code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it right for other constraints, but for `uriLabel`'s and `otherTestView`'s bottom constraints you just forgot to make them **active**:

```
uriLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherTestView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
otherTestView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

---

Also the problem is that you're setting `otherTestView`'s and `testView`'s constraints equal to superview's anchors. This cause that `otherTestView` (added later) overlaps `testView`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I have updated my TableViewCell and I have simlified my example. However, now I only see the "otherTestView" and not the "testView" :/ Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @FuchurKool this is because you're setting both views' constraints equal to superview's constraints, so `otherTestView` overlaps `testView`

Comment: I see, so could you provide me the example how this would be done right? I thought that if I put the BottomAnchor of the topView to the TopAnchor of the BottomView, it should be on top of it?

Comment: @FuchurKool look, imagine it like you're giving paper over the other. You can't see first paper which is under second paper. What you have to do is to put papers next to each other. Then you'll be able to see both papers.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be done? Should I use the method insertSubview on the second view?

Comment: @FuchurKool try to learn more about **constraints**. The  main princip is, that view has to know its width, height, x position and y position. This you can do by setting constraints. For example by setting view's leading, trailing, top and bottom. It's hard to explain it in comment, so I would recommend you to read some articles/watch some tutorials to better understanding what I mean.